# looking the messages into the queue

Tags: jms, message-queue

I am putting some data into the queue and some times I need to check the queue count with I have to also look upto that what is the message in the queue can You please advise any freeware software through which I can track the queue and look the queue count plus also look the messages in to the queue

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom solution yourself using a [QueueBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html). You could print the queue contents out, or perhaps write it out as HTML to a browser.

There's also a pretty decent tool with excellent browsing capabilities (among other functionality) called [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home).